# How to get the output of timeout command without using a shell script

Tags: java, linux, timeout

I am using a ssh command executor in java which runs the command and gets the output in stderr, stdout and an integer exit value. I am trying run a command with timeout like,

```
timeout 5s COMMAND
```

Is there a way to get a response in the stderr or the stdout so that I can know whether the command was timed out or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use shell scripting capabilities which should work fine with the ssh command executor.

```
timeout 5s sleep 1s && (>&2 echo "Successful") || (>&2 echo "Timed out")
```